# re-arranging two or more pandas dataframes for a seaborn graph

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Two Laboratories have carried out a series of measurements:

1. In three experimental conditions where the instruments are known to show a different response (`test_1`, `test_2`, `test_3`)
2. Using two different makes and models of instruments (foo, bar)
3. Repeating their measurements on multiple copies of each instrument model that they own, which have individual serial numbers, and including measurements on instruments that they lent one another for an interlaboratory comparison (same serial number measured at both Labs).

The two Labs now want to pool all their data together and draw some conclusions on the properties of the two instruments from their combined dataset. For a start, they want to have a look at all data together in a Seaborn categorical plot.

Adapting a little bit from the Pandas [cookbook examples on MultiIndexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html?highlight=multindex#multiindexing) This is the way data were communicated by each Lab:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot

df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['test_1', 'test_2' ,'test_3'],
                'foo_110': [1.1, 1.18, 1.19],
                'foo_112': [1.15, 1.25, 1.25],
                'bar_888': [1.11, 1.15, 1.16],
                'bar_657': [1.14, 1.16, 1.18]}
               ) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['test_1', 'test_2' ,'test_3'],
                'foo_105': [1.13, 1.17, 1.18],
                'foo_112': [1.16, 1.26, 1.28],
                'foo_167': [1.18, 1.23, 1.27],
                'bar_888': [1.10, 1.14, 1.18],
                'bar_415': [1.12, 1.15, 1.16]}
               )
```

To prepare their data for their Seaborn plot, dataframes are reorganised in their indices, `stacked()`, and concatenated along `axis = 0`:

```
df = df.set_index('test')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df.columns])
df = df.stack().reset_index()

df1 = df1.set_index('test')
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df1.columns])
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index()

dfAll = pd.concat((df, df1), axis = 0, sort= False)
dfAll.columns = ['test', 's.no.', 'bar', 'foo']
```

producing

```
print(dfAll.head(10))
     test s.no.   bar   foo
0  test_1   110   NaN  1.10
1  test_1   112   NaN  1.15
2  test_1   657  1.14   NaN
3  test_1   888  1.11   NaN
4  test_2   110   NaN  1.18
5  test_2   112   NaN  1.25
6  test_2   657  1.16   NaN
7  test_2   888  1.15   NaN
8  test_3   110   NaN  1.19
9  test_3   112   NaN  1.25
```

Plotting all data together for the 'bar' instrument:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
dfAllplot = sns.catplot(x="test", y ="bar", data=dfAll, hue='s.no.')
```

[image: Results for instrument type **bar**, Lab_1 and Lab_2 combined]

What the two labs want to do now is to retain their capacity to distinguish the data points that were originated by `Lab_1` and by `Lab_2`, as well as using additional information provided by the two labs which includes magnitude of the error bars, which is different for `test_1`, `test_2`, and `test_3`.

The Lab datum is easily provided by adding a column to the `df` and `df1` after resetting their index and before concatenating.

```
df['Lab'] = 'Lab_1' 
df1['Lab'] = 'Lab_2'
```

[image: Same as above, but with hue set to 'Lab']

The problem which I have not solved is how to preserve the data after `stacking()` when additional information is provided for each `test_x`. Adding a column `df1['urel']` with the relative uncertainties after rearranging the `Index` as a `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('test')
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df1.columns])
df1['urel'] = [0.015, 0.014, 0.013]
```

yields

```
df1
Out[137]: 
         foo               bar         urel
         105   112   167   888   415       
test                                       
test_1  1.13  1.16  1.18  1.10  1.12  0.015
test_2  1.17  1.26  1.23  1.14  1.15  0.014
test_3  1.18  1.28  1.27  1.18  1.16  0.013
```

then

```
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index()
df1['Lab'] = 'Lab_2'
```

yields the wanted result for the `'Lab'` column but not for `'urel'`, which carries the original value only for some rows and cannot be used for further plotting instructions.

```
print(df1.head(10))
     test level_1   bar   foo   urel    Lab
0  test_1     105   NaN  1.13    NaN  Lab_2
1  test_1     112   NaN  1.16    NaN  Lab_2
2  test_1     167   NaN  1.18    NaN  Lab_2
3  test_1     415  1.12   NaN    NaN  Lab_2
4  test_1     888  1.10   NaN    NaN  Lab_2
5  test_1           NaN   NaN  0.015  Lab_2
6  test_2     105   NaN  1.17    NaN  Lab_2
7  test_2     112   NaN  1.26    NaN  Lab_2
8  test_2     167   NaN  1.23    NaN  Lab_2
9  test_2     415  1.15   NaN    NaN  Lab_2
```

When should `'urel'` be added to the dataframe? 
If added before MultiIndexing, i.e. right from the start, multi-indexing, stacking and resetting as done here 'breaks' again `'urel'`.
Or maybe `stack()` is not the correct method for the example offered here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A solution based on pandas methods

This solution uses the `melt()` method for `DataFrames`.
Re-defining the two dataframes so that columns are easier to handle for the melt method:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'urel' : [0.020, 0.025, 0.018],
                     'HVL' : [0.156, 0.180, 0.195],
                     'test': ['test_1', 'test_2' ,'test_3'],
                     'Lab' : ['Lab_1', 'Lab_1', 'Lab_1'],
                     'foo_110': [1.1, 1.18, 1.19],
                     'foo_112': [1.15, 1.25, 1.25],
                     'bar_657': [1.14, 1.16, 1.18],
                     'bar_888': [1.11, 1.15, 1.16],
                     }
                  )

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'urel' : [0.020, 0.025, 0.018],
                     'HVL' : [0.156, 0.180, 0.195],
                     'test': ['test_1', 'test_2' ,'test_3'],
                     'Lab' : ['Lab_2', 'Lab_2', 'Lab_2'],
                     'foo_105': [1.13, 1.17, 1.18],
                     'foo_112': [1.16, 1.26, 1.28],
                     'foo_167': [1.18, 1.23, 1.27],
                     'bar_888': [1.10, 1.14, 1.18],
                     'bar_415': [1.12, 1.15, 1.16],
                    }
                )
for df in (df_1, df_2):
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df.columns])

df_1 = df_1.melt(id_vars=(df_1.columns.tolist()[:4]),
                  value_vars=df_1.columns.tolist()[4:],
                  var_name=['model', 'ser.no']
                  )
df_2 = df_2.melt(id_vars=(df_2.columns.tolist()[:4]),
                  value_vars=df_2.columns.tolist()[4:],
                  var_name=['model', 'ser.no']
                  )

colnames = ['urel', 'HVL', 'test', 'Lab', 'model', 'ser.no', 'value'] 
df_1.columns = colnames
df_2.columns = colnames
dfAll = df_1.append(df_2, ignore_index=True)
```

yields a `DataFrame` without the unnecessary `NaN` values and, perhaps more importantly, the two instruments `foo` and `bar` under the same column named `model`.

```
print(dfAll.head(10))
    urel    HVL    test    Lab model ser.no  value
0  0.020  0.156  test_1  Lab_1   foo    110   1.10
1  0.025  0.180  test_2  Lab_1   foo    110   1.18
2  0.018  0.195  test_3  Lab_1   foo    110   1.19
3  0.020  0.156  test_1  Lab_1   foo    112   1.15
4  0.025  0.180  test_2  Lab_1   foo    112   1.25
5  0.018  0.195  test_3  Lab_1   foo    112   1.25
6  0.020  0.156  test_1  Lab_1   bar    657   1.14
7  0.025  0.180  test_2  Lab_1   bar    657   1.16
8  0.018  0.195  test_3  Lab_1   bar    657   1.18
9  0.020  0.156  test_1  Lab_1   bar    888   1.11
```

This better structure is suitable for a `seaborn` plot using `catplot`, which returns a `FacetGrid` object with each instrument model occupying a different facet

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.set(style="ticks")
g = sns.catplot(x="test", # returns a FacetGrid object for further editing
            # see https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid
            # https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot
            y = 'value', 
            data=dfAll, 
            hue='Lab', 
            col='model', 
            dodge=False, 
            kind='swarm',
            sharey = True
            )
(g.set_axis_labels("tests", "value")
 .savefig('facetgrid_example.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
          )
```

[image: The image resulting from the catplot after using the melt() method]

Answer (score 0):

#### A not very elegant solution

suppose the original dataframe, complete with all info, is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['test_1', 'test_2' ,'test_3'],
                   'foo_110': [1.1, 1.18, 1.19],
                   'foo_112': [1.15, 1.25, 1.25],
                   'bar_888': [1.11, 1.15, 1.16],
                   'bar_657': [1.14, 1.16, 1.18],
                   'urel' : [0.020, 0.025, 0.018],
                   'HVL' : [0.156, 0.180, 0.195]}
                  )
df = df.set_index('test')
```

where `'urel'` and `'HVL'` are two columns that would suffer from the problems illustrated earlier. Taking them out of the `stacking()` process and then back in with a function does what desidered

```
def stack_for_seaborn(df, separate=['urel', 'HVL']):
    '''
    Alternative stacking() of a pandas dataframe for seaborn plotting
    First, some columns are extracted from the stacking() process
    Second, stacking() is applied
    Third, the 'separate' portion of the df is appended considering the new index
    '''
    idx = df.index
    addnl = df[separate]
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df.columns])
    df.drop(separate, axis = 1, level=0, inplace=True)
    df = df.stack().reset_index()
    df = df.set_index('test')
    for t in idx:
        for c in addnl.columns:
            df.loc[t, c] = addnl[c].loc[t]
    return df

df = stack_for_seaborn(df)
df['Lab'] = 'Lab_1' 
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns =   ['test', 's.no.', 'bar', 'foo', 'urel', 'HVL', 'Lab']
```

yields the result that was sought, however a pandas built-in method may be much nicer.

```
print(df.head(10))
     test s.no.   bar   foo   urel    HVL    Lab
0  test_1   110   NaN  1.10  0.020  0.156  Lab_1
1  test_1   112   NaN  1.15  0.020  0.156  Lab_1
2  test_1   657  1.14   NaN  0.020  0.156  Lab_1
3  test_1   888  1.11   NaN  0.020  0.156  Lab_1
4  test_2   110   NaN  1.18  0.025  0.180  Lab_1
5  test_2   112   NaN  1.25  0.025  0.180  Lab_1
6  test_2   657  1.16   NaN  0.025  0.180  Lab_1
7  test_2   888  1.15   NaN  0.025  0.180  Lab_1
8  test_3   110   NaN  1.19  0.018  0.195  Lab_1
9  test_3   112   NaN  1.25  0.018  0.195  Lab_1
```